# Как обойти скрытые папки при переборе файлов?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

При переборе файлов в папках есть одна проблема, это скрытые файлы 
(переберает по ним тоже), как можно обойти скрытые папки?

---

Собираю файлы таким способом:

```
List<string> Browsers = new List<string>();
List<string> APD = new List<string>(); 
string[] BrPaths =
{
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),  
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
};
foreach (string paths in BrPaths) 
APD.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(paths));

foreach (string e in APD)
Browsers.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(e, "File", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

---

P.S: В C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ **Скрытая папка(Application Data)** Которую  нужно обойти

Comment: Никак. Обходите рекурсивно и ловите исключения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
  DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\myFolder");
    if ((directory.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0)
    {
       //значит это не скрытая папка
    }
```

Comment: @GooliveR, напирмер так: `APD.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(paths).Where(x=>new DirectoryInfo(x).Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden==0));`

Comment: @GooliveR там похоже скобки я забыл: `x=>(new DirectoryInfo(x).Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden)==0`. В общем-то, как в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прочитать атрибуты файла или папки и проверить на наличие того что элемент скрытый. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes(v=vs.110).aspx